# Undefined variables and indexes

Tags: php

I'm starting to get annoyed by having to check if all form fields have been filled every time with every single form. Since client side isn't reliable to have data validation on I need to do this server side with a thousand !empty's. Is there any way similar to throw-catch I can use to catch undefined variable or index errors?

Comment: maybe you should start working with classes provided by frameworks like ZF (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html). Those take care of a lot of pain you have by validating forms yourself. Also they are much more reliable and tested than your own code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution could look like this:

```
$indexes = array('foo1', 'foo2', '......');
foreach($indexes as $index) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$index])) {
        die('you are missing POST:' . $index);
    }
}
```

Mostly there are better ways to do that when using a framework. Like custom error messages for every param and validation. I once crafted a couple of classes for this on my own.

You wrote:

> I'm starting to get annoyed by having to check if all form fields have been filled every time with every single form.

Although I understand what you mean ;) ,you should not get annoyed by this, as taking care about input data is one of the most important tasks in a web application. You should craft some classes for this like me or use a framework.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought of, **after asking the question** of course. As always :D. I'm building my own framework kind of thingy and I don't wanna use any other frameworks! :P

Comment: `I'm building my own framework kind of thingy and I don't wanna use any other frameworks!` If you ask me, it's a good decision to learn how things work. :)

Comment: Which things? Which things?

Comment: I just meant, you are on the right track. It is better to code some own stuff and learn how PHP and web applications work instead of using a framework.

Comment: Oh I thought you were advising me :D. I am following moog's thought "I'd rather lose by a mile because I built my own car, than win by an inch because someone else built it for me." Except it's with sites and stuff :D Thanks again! :P

Comment: ok, happy coding! :) btw, if I once publish my `WebRequest` framework on github, I'll drop a comment here, anyway. ;)

Comment: I'll be happy to see that! :P